# How to search for a range of cells in excel for a particular string and return the value of the cell that does not contain that string

Tags: excel

I have a row containing a series of "FALSE" and one cell containing a country value such as "Australia"

How to go through these cells and return the country name in another column

For eg

```
A1     B1    C1    D1    E1
False  False False False Australia
```

How to go through A1 through E1 and return the value of the cell not containing "False"

Comment: with VBA or a formula?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what you want to do with the value and you didn’t state if you’ll will encounter multiple occurrence of a cell that doesn’t contain False. But If you run the macro while the range is selected, this will show a message of for the cell value and the range

```
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel in Selection 
   If cel.value <> “False” then MsgBox cel.value & “ in cell “ & cel.Address
Next cel
```

Comment: There is only one occurence of the cell that does not contain "False" and I want to store the unique value in a different column

Comment: @user11162755 what column?

Comment: Just another column in this sheet to contain the non False value

Comment: FOr instance in this case add that value in F1